# Delete text within quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I want to remove strings within the double quotes or single quotes or backticks along with the enclosing characters.

Input is:

```
Lorem ipsum "'dolor sit amet consectetur'" adipiscing "elite"  ellentesque 

scelerisque 'tortor' tortor in `vestibulum` dolor
```

Expected output:

```
Lorem ipsum adipiscing ellentesque scelerisque tortor in dolor
```

I have this code, but there is no change in the result. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
line.replaceAll("[\'\"\\`].*[\'\"\\`]$", "");
```

Comment: Can there be escaped quotes of the same type, like `"he said \"foo\""`?

Comment: `replace` will not change the string, but create a new string. You have to assign it to some variable.

Comment: @tobias_k all of those inside would also be deleted. I'm appending it to a string builder sb.append(line.replaceAll("^[\'\"\\`].*[\'\"\\`]$", ""));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three problems with your regex.

1. It matches text from *any* one of `` "'` `` to *any* one of `` "'` ``, not necessarily the same one that started the match.
2. `*` is greedy, meaning it will match text from the first `"`, `'`, or `` ` `` to the *very last one* in the line.
3. Because your regex ends with `$`, it will only match text if that text ends with the end of the entire string.

You can try it this way:

```
sb.append(line.replaceAll("(?:([\"'`])[^\\1]*?\\1)\\s+|\r?\n", ""));
```

Input:

```
Lorem ipsum "'dolor sit amet consectetur'" adipiscing "elite"  ellentesque 

scelerisque 'tortor' tortor in `vestibulum` dolor
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum adipiscing ellentesque scelerisque tortor in dolor
```

There is an explanation and demonstration of that regex here: http://regex101.com/r/iK3fQ8

Answer (score 2):

like this may be:

```
\".*?\"|\'.*?\'|`.*`
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/lB4xS2

Answer (score 1):

Change your greedy matcher `.*` to `.+?`(non greedy).

And assign the replaced value.

Full code:

```
line = line.replaceAll("([\'\"\\`]).+?\1", "");
```

Thanks tobias_k for pointing out that I could use backreference.

Also check for java's escaping rules and escape accordingly.

Comment: What about `"Lorem 'Ipsum'" Dolor`? Also you kept the useless `$`.

Comment: @Robin, well It will remove `Lorem Ipsum`. OP wanted to remove strings between quotes. Also I edited and removed `$`. Thanks :)

Comment: You could use groups to find matching quotes, something like `"([\'\"\\`]).+?\1"` (not sure whether this is supported, though)

Comment: @AmitJoki: nope: http://regex101.com/r/eF2gJ8. The first match would be `"lorem'`

Answer (score 1):

For better readability of your code I would split this into several regexps:

```
line = line.replaceAll("\".*?\"", "");
line = line.replaceAll("'.*?'", "");
line = line.replaceAll("`.*?`", "");
```

(untested, there might be another espacing necessary)

Answer (score 1):

```
l=line;
l=l.replaceAll("\"[^\"]+\"","");
l=l.replaceAll("'[^\"]+'","");
l=l.replaceAll("`[^\"]+`","");
```

---

explain:

1. `"` - start a string with `"`
2. `[^"]+` - find at least one chart that is not `"`
3. `"` - find a closing `"`

same for ' and `

Comment: Can you please explain this code (in your answer)? You might get more upvotes that way!

Comment: +1, but shouldn't they be replaced with an empty string?

Comment: he said delete text within quotes not the quotes themselves. obviously, replace with empty, if quotes are not necessary as well.

Comment: I know, but look at the input and expected output.